# how to handle 'Invalid token error :209' after parse migration objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, back4app

how to handle this error 'invalid session error (209)' in my code I have use below code :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Query"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query whereKey:@"converted" equalTo:@NO];
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{ if (!error){ // success }
else { [ParseErrorHandlingController handleParseError:error];}}
```

Comment: in appdelegate.m I have use this code:

Comment: probably log out and log in again

Comment: [Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
        configuration.applicationId = @"App_ID";
        configuration.clientKey = @"Client_Id";
        configuration.server = @"https://parseapi.back4app.com/";
        
    }]];
 [PFUser enableRevocableSessionInBackground];

Comment: I have follow this steps:

Comment: e. On the Data Browser, manually delete the Session object. This revokes the session token on your phone.

f. Navigate to any part of your app that issues a Parse Query. This should throw the "invalid session token" error and invoke your error-handling logic from Step 1. Make sure your error-handling logic works as intended.

g. Log into your app again and make sure the app is still functional. The Data Browser should now show 1 Session.

h. Log out of your app. The Data Browser's Session table should now be empty.

Comment: I want to be manage the logout and login session using geting this error

Comment: haven't worked much with back4app, so wait for a answer. Try searching for tutorials of it

Answer (score 0):

For what I could check at Back4App's and Parse's Docs I'd point out two problems that you might be having given the codes shown by your post.

First, the SDK Initialization used by you might present some typos or syntax problems as you can see by checking the one suggested by B4A's Documentation:

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
   configuration.applicationId = @"YOUR_APP_ID";
   configuration.clientKey = @"YOUR_CLIENT_KEY";
   configuration.server = @"https://parseapi.back4app.com";
   configuration.localDatastoreEnabled = YES; // If you need to enable local data store
}]];
```

Then, I found a typo inside your if-else clause as you have not closed the "if" section when added the comment, here:

> ```
> [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
> { if (!error){ // success }
> else { [ParseErrorHandlingController handleParseError:error];}}
> ```

Maybe those were the main reasons of your issue.